# How do I get token for Oracle OCI with Java SDK

Tags: java, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to understand how do I get **Oracle OCI** token with **Java SDK**.

And then use it (in headers, '**Authorization**' and '**Date**')

I went over the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdk_authentication_methods.htm) and that as well [documentation2](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/javasdkgettingstarted.htm#Configur).

But none of those methods answered my question:

How do I get the '**token**' and '**date**' so I can use them in a Rest API call (put them in the headers).

Did anybody used Oracle OCI with Java SDK to get that?

Thanks!

I've tried couple of the **SDK **methods in the documentation.
But I couldn't found a method that get the '**token**' and '**date**' so I can use them in a **Rest API** call (put them in the headers).

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the use case for getting the token and then plug it into rest api calls without the need for the sdk? Is there something that is not supported in sdk for your use case?

OCI Java SDK provides a raw request signer, so you could use that instead of using other tools -> https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/SDKDocs/javasdkconcepts.htm#rawrequests

Comment: Hi, thanks!
This is what I'm starting to think.
The use case is to invoke Data science Rest API related calls that uses headers like: Authorization -> signature, which is signed settings like tenancy/passphrase/private key etc.
Date ->
But I couldn't find the documentation for that for Java

Comment: An update:

I've found a relevant documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/signingrequests.htm#seven__Java

But if there's an example of implementation in Java, it would be great, thanks!